# What's the easiest way to set up a 2-hour alarm?

Tags: cron, scheduling

I want my computer to play some given .mp3 every 2 hours.  I want it to run at startup, and be modifiable with a given .conf file.  The choice of .mp3 will also be in the .conf file.

The reason is, I need this to remind me to eat regularly.

Now, I'm familiar with C, but I don't know anything about daemonising C programs.  I'm also not very familiar with CRON, so if that's an option, I'd need further instruction.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Cron is perfectly suited for this. Do you have a script which plays the music? Do you launch a special command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just source the conf file in your bash script and use [mpg123](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpg123) to play the mp3. For example in `~/.music-cron`:

```
TARGET_MP3="$HOME/file.mp3"
```

And in the bash script:

```
. "$HOME/.music-cron"
mpg123 $TARGET_MP3
```

Then use cron to schedule the script every two hours and after the system boots up:

```
0 */2 * * * /path/to/script.sh
@reboot sleep 60 && /path/to/script.sh
```

The `sleep 60` is just in there because you probably don't want it to immediate play it just in case there are other kinds of startup audio notifications going on at the same time.

Out of morbid curiosity, why are you needing to eat every two hours? This is one of the more interesting questions I've ever seen on here.

**EDIT:**

As Doug pointed out a better solution would be to ignore the 2-hour cron scheduling and just put `echo $0 | at now + 2 hours` as the last line in the script.

Comment: Won't `* */2` run the script every minute in even-numbered hours?

Comment: eep. Good point. I typed too quickly so I had an excuse for asking that last question.

Comment: I'm curious about his reason for the regular eating, too. ;) Also, I'm trying to come up with an elegant way to execute the script at two-hours intervals after the system booted rather than at */2:00 o'clock. Imagine him turning on the computer at 9:59 or something: The poor guy would have to go for a meal twice in the span of less than two minutes! ;) — @KorganRivera Sorry for making fun of you. This probably isn't a laughing matter, but your question did a great job at breaking the monotony.

Comment: By the way, @JoelDavis, is there any particular reason to use `/etc/sysconfig/chowDown` as the path for the config file?

Comment: How about `echo /path/to/script.sh | at now + 2 hours` in your system startup and having the same command as the last line in the script?

Comment: @n.st Not really, it's just where I'm used to putting various system-wide configuration files. A lot of the init scripts on RHEL source files in that directory. I see what you mean about the two minutes. I suppose you could do a `touch /tmp/chowdown.ran` at the end of each invocation and then start the script by checking `find /tmp/chowDown.ran -mmin +59` for output and branch as appropriate.

Comment: Haha, more questions about the eating than the problem :)  Well I'm about to get back into weight training, so I'll be back on my 4000 calories a day. And I have a hard time sometimes reminding myself to eat every 2 hours; I get caught up doing other things. :)

Comment: @n.st Yeah I thought about that too.  If I could somehow keep track of the time since the last alarm, modulus 2 hours, that would work.

Comment: Eh, I guess I should have said either `touch -m /tmp/chowDown.ran` or used `-amin +59` above. Doug's `at` solution is probably the cleanest though since doesn't depend on any additional files being created/checked or require the script to have any conditional branching. He should probably post that as a separate answer, though, since it was his idea.

Comment: @JoelDavis I've [made a few changes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/41959) to your answer (see the comment for details) — hope you don't mind.

Comment: Don't apologize, we're all here to get and give the best information possible.